# Creating Connect 4 Winning Outcomes

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a basic JavaFX program that represents the Connect 4 game. I have created everything except the winning outcomes. When one of the users has their disk color 4 times in a row (either diagonally, vertically, or horizontally), the program will announce the winner. I am struggling on this part. How do I make it so that the program will recognize when someone has won the game. Any ideas?
Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
public class ConnectFour extends Application
{
   private BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
   private GridPane gPane = new GridPane();
   private boolean player1 = true;
   private int row0 = 5;
   private int row1 = 5;
   private int row2 = 5;
   private int row3 = 5;
   private int row4 = 5;
   private int row5 = 5;
   private int row6 = 5;
   private Label label = new Label("Player1 turn");
   public void start(Stage stage)
   {
      //Create the Grid
      createGrid();

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      stage.setTitle("Connect 4");
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();

      //Start the game
      initiateGame();



   }

   //Create the grid method
   public void createGrid()
   {


      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
         for (int j =0; j < 7; j++)
         {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            rect.setFill(null);
            gPane.add(rect, j, i);
         }  
      }

      pane.getChildren().add(gPane);

   }

   public void initiateGame()
   {
      HBox hBox = new HBox(10);




         label.setFont(Font.font(20)); 

         TextField colField = new TextField();
         colField.setPrefColumnCount(1);

         Button submit = new Button("Submit");

         submit.setOnAction(e->
         {
            int col = Integer.parseInt(colField.getText());
            dropDisk(col, player1);
         });

         hBox.getChildren().addAll(label, colField, submit);

         pane.setBottom(hBox);

   }


   public void dropDisk(int col, boolean playerOne)
   {

      if (playerOne)
      {
         switch (col)
         {
            case 0: Circle circ = new Circle(25); circ.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ, col, row0);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ, HPos.CENTER); row0--; label.setText("Player2 turn");
            player1 = false; break;

            case 1: Circle circ1 = new Circle(25); circ1.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ1, col, row1);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ1, HPos.CENTER); row1--; label.setText("Player2 turn");
            player1 = false; break;

            case 2: Circle circ2 = new Circle(25); circ2.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ2, col, row2);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ2, HPos.CENTER); row2--; label.setText("Player2 turn");
            player1 = false; break;

            case 3: Circle circ3 = new Circle(25); circ3.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ3, col, row3);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ3, HPos.CENTER); row3--; label.setText("Player2 turn");
            player1 = false; break;

            case 4: Circle circ4 = new Circle(25); circ4.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ4, col, row4);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ4, HPos.CENTER); row4--; label.setText("Player2 turn");
            player1 = false; break;

            case 5: Circle circ5 = new Circle(25); circ5.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ5, col, row5);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ5, HPos.CENTER); row5--; label.setText("Player2 turn");
            player1 = false; break;

            case 6: Circle circ6 = new Circle(25); circ6.setFill(Color.RED); gPane.add(circ6, col, row6);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ6, HPos.CENTER); row6--;
            player1 = false; break;

            default: System.out.println("Incorrect column");
               break;

         }
      }

      else
      {
         switch (col)
         {
            case 0: Circle circ = new Circle(25); circ.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ, col, row0);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ, HPos.CENTER); row0--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            case 1: Circle circ1 = new Circle(25); circ1.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ1, col, row1);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ1, HPos.CENTER); row1--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            case 2: Circle circ2 = new Circle(25); circ2.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ2, col, row2);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ2, HPos.CENTER); row2--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            case 3: Circle circ3 = new Circle(25); circ3.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ3, col, row3);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ3, HPos.CENTER); row3--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            case 4: Circle circ4 = new Circle(25); circ4.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ4, col, row4);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ4, HPos.CENTER); row4--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            case 5: Circle circ5 = new Circle(25); circ5.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ5, col, row5);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ5, HPos.CENTER); row5--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            case 6: Circle circ6 = new Circle(25); circ6.setFill(Color.YELLOW); gPane.add(circ6, col, row6);
            gPane.setHalignment(circ6, HPos.CENTER); row6--; label.setText("Player1 turn");
               player1 = true; break;
            default: System.out.println("Incorrect column");
               break;

         }
      }

   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you a snippet of a game I was making, called Omok. It was a connect 5 game. I used a 2D array to store my data, 0 being empty, 1 being player 1, 2 being player 2.

It basically loops through horizontal, vertical, and the two diagonals to check if it is connected in 5 ways. It is done by storing the value of the last move, and checking from there.

b is my 2D integer array (board).

```
public int winCheck(int lastRow, int lastCol, int check){
    if(horizontal(lastRow, lastCol, check) == 5
            || vertical(lastRow, lastCol, check) == 5
            || h1check(lastRow,lastCol,check) == 5
            || h2check(lastRow, lastCol, check) == 5){
        this.winner = check;
        return this.winner;
    }//end if
    return this.winner;
}//end winCheck

private int horizontal(int lastRow, int lastCol, int check){
    int count = 1;
    int numMove = 1;
    while(lastCol - numMove >= 0){
        if(b[lastRow][lastCol - numMove] == check){
            count ++;
            numMove ++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while for leftMove

    numMove = 1;
    while(lastCol + numMove < b.length){
        if(b[lastRow][lastCol + numMove] == check){
            count++;
            numMove++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while
    return count;
}//end

private int vertical(int lastRow, int lastCol, int check){
    int count = 1;
    int numMove = 1;
    while(lastRow - numMove >= 0){
        if(b[lastRow - numMove][lastCol] == check){
            count ++;
            numMove ++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while for leftMove

    numMove = 1;
    while(lastRow + numMove < b.length){
        if(b[lastRow + numMove][lastCol] == check){
            count++;
            numMove++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while
    return count;
}//end

private int h1check(int lastRow, int lastCol, int check){
    int count = 1;
    int numMove = 1;
    while(lastRow - numMove >= 0 && lastCol - numMove >= 0){
        if(b[lastRow - numMove][lastCol - numMove] == check){
            count ++;
            numMove ++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while for leftMove

    numMove = 1;
    while(lastRow + numMove < b.length && lastCol + numMove < b.length){
        if(b[lastRow + numMove][lastCol + numMove] == check){
            count++;
            numMove++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while
    return count;
}//end

private int h2check(int lastRow, int lastCol, int check){
    int count = 1;
    int numMove = 1;
    while(lastRow + numMove < b.length && lastCol - numMove >= 0){
        if(b[lastRow + numMove][lastCol - numMove] == check){
            count ++;
            numMove ++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while for leftMove

    numMove = 1;
    while(lastRow - numMove >= 0 && lastCol + numMove < b.length){
        if(b[lastRow - numMove][lastCol + numMove] == check){
            count++;
            numMove++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }//end while
    return count;
}//end
```